# From Uri to Path and back to Uri

Tags: android, parsing, path, uri

I’m using some big pictures that are stored in External Memory. I decode them, resize them and set the small bitmaps to various imageviews.

I keep track of those large images by storing their Uri’s. When the app stops, I convert Uri to paths and save them as Strings is a SQLite base:.

```
File myFile = new File(provider.getImageUri().toString());
cv.put(DBHelper.DB_IMAGEPATH, myFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

At this point the path to the image looks like:

/content/media/.. and everything works ok.

When the app resumes I read the path from database and convert it to Uri:

```
File tempFile = new File(cursor.getString(imagePathColIndex);
mUri = (Uri.fromFile(mFile));
```

Now the path in new mUri looks like:
File:///content/... And there is a IONotFound exception.

Answer (score 1):

You should try with

```
File tempFile = new File(cursor.getString(imagePathColIndex));
mUri = Uri.parse(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Testing with the following code

```
String path = "/content/media";
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
Log.e(TAG, uri.toString()); //print file:///content/media

uri = Uri.parse(path);
Log.e(TAG, uri.toString()); //print /content/media
```

**EDIT**
To read the image can you try

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(Uri.parse(path)));
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code is correct from the point of view of the string path. But when I try to get the image from that Uri, I still have: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /content:/media/external/images/media/520892

Comment: It consider your path as a content provider Uri. Which is strange. Why is there a `:` after content ?

Comment: When I later try to decode the image of lesser size from that Uri in such line: BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri), null, o);

Comment: Do you have a content provider ? Can you provide the blocking code ?

Comment: No, I don't. This Uri works before saving to SQLite database, but after I restore the Uri from the base, I get this error.

Comment: Ok, after I restored the Uri, I try to get the size of the image like this: 
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        try {
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri), null, o);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

sorry for the jammed text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93071/discussion-between-maloubobola-and-rommex).